# Is it possible to change the size of a div dynamically with D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have d3 code that produces this svg. It is a snippet of a larger dynamic graph that has an image within a div within a foreignobject within a group element.

```
<svg>
    <g class = "node" transform = "translate(711.2977697849274,120)">
        <circle class = "cirBG" r = "70"></circle>
        <foreignobject class = "fObj" x = "-25" y = "-25" height = "50" width = "50" overflow = "visible">
           <div class = "logo"
             style = "background-image: url(imgs/ppl/gbProfile.png); height: 50px; width: 50px; background-size: 50px 50px; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
        </foreignobject>
    </g>  
</svg>
```

Then I have d3 code to the change the size of .logo div but none of it works

```
var logoDiv = cNode.select( ".logo" );

// tried strict javascript //////////////////////   
logoDiv.style.width = '"' + logoWidth + 'px"';
logoDiv.style.height = '"' + logoHeight + 'px"';

// tried d3 style ////////////
logoDiv.style( "width", logoWidth  + 'px' );
logoDiv.style( "height", logoHeight  + 'px' );
```

I saw some examples of Jquery and will use it if it's the only option but trying to keep it simple to existing d3 library. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to resize the `foreignobject` instead?

Comment: @MarcoCI Yes, it is necessary to do so anyways because the div is contained within it. It does not resize the div with it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d3 style seems to work. Did you select `logoDiv` with d3?

The following code works for me:

```
var logoDiv = d3.select( ".logo" );
logoDiv.style('background-color',"blue");
logoDiv.style('height','200px')
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8m6kT/

Also, you should probably use the `xhtml` namespace for the div as it is not inferred in a foreignObject:

```
<foreignobject class = "fObj" x = "-25" y = "-25" height = "50" width = "50" overflow ="visible">
    <xhtml:div class = "logo" style = "..."></xhtml:div>
</foreignobject>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Christopher Chiche!
Yes, I used D3 to select and now it works. I must of had other conflicting tags or something going on before.
The xhtml prevents the background-image from loading for some reason.